# Libreoffice crashes after upgrade to Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: libreoffice, crash

Since I've run the do-release-upgrade command, I cannot use libreoffice.

I tried

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice.core` (which seems to remove most stuff, including `libreoffice.base`)
2. and then `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

When I launch it, I see a list of recent documents, but as soon as I try to open anything it crashes.

I tried to launch it via the command line (by typing "libreoffice").

```
The error is : (soffice 7674): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
```

But someone on [Arch Linux bug #54594](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/54594) says that this error message is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "anything"?

Comment: Any files created by Libre Office (writer, draw or spreadsheet).

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded a new version of libreoffice (6.0.1) from their site and uncompressed the file with ark.

Then I went to the DEBS folder and typed : sudo dpkg -i *.deb

This installed without any trouble LibreOffice 6.0.1 and it hasn't crashed yet. It opened the file I wanted to open in the first place.

This is not a solution, but it'll do as a workaround.

Comment: My message and the solution I found could help other users with the same problem... The problem did NOT go away on its own. I took the time to come back to this site and to post the workaround I found. BTW, Libre Office 6.0.1 is still functioning properly on my pc.

Comment: IMHO there isn't anything wrong with a workaround. Personally I voted the question as unclear due to the usage of the phrase "... try to open anything..." All having a question closed does is remove it from the open questions list, removing the ability for others to answer it. It doesn't mean that others can't find it in fact it shows up in the top 5 for me on a [google search.](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Libreoffice+crashes+after+upgrade&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)People can still upvote it as well. I wouldn't be concerned about it if I were you. Take concerns to meta. :)